# Close as dup but redirect to another closed question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I came cross this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028666/what-is-the-diffrence-between-a-string-array-and-char-array-declared-using-point#52028666) and it was closed as a duplicate and forwarded to [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801209/char-vs-stdstring-in-c). Now both are closed.

My first issue is that it seems that if A is a dup of B, and B is closed as non-constructuve, then A should be closed as non-constructive and deleted, since there shouldn't be any extant question with an answer since it's non-constructive. In this case, I cannot see how either question would be considered non-constructive, so can [char* vs std::string in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801209/char-vs-stdstring-in-c) be opened since it seems like a perfectly on-topic constructive programming question?

Comment: But not constructive is not a close reason any more.

Comment: @Catija So then my position would be that the original '09 question should be opened. I don't think it should've ever been closed since it's a very constructive and not-merely-opinion question on the differences of `string` and `char *` in C++.